# Spring boot app behind nginx redirects improperly

Tags: spring-boot, nginx

I'm attempting to run my spring boot app behind nginx (on a dev machine), using a config file I found at [Running a Spring Boot app behind nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125502/running-a-spring-boot-app-behind-nginx). Firefox however says it isn’t redirecting properly, and the Network tab in the javascript console confirms many 302 redirects.

This is nginx.conf I'm using:

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

keepalive_timeout  65;

upstream tomcat {
    server localhost:8080;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log  main;

    location / {
            proxy_pass              $scheme://tomcat/$request_uri;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Indeed, the mentioned log file has many lines like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Apr/2018:11:25:38 +0200] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0" "-"
```

It is redirecting to /login, which it should in fact:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired private AuthService authService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(authService);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why calls to /login seem to be redirected to /login instead of returing the page on that url?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but you should probably be using `proxy_pass http://tomcat;` The `$scheme` is inappropriate here, and the `$request_uri` may be doubly encoding the redirect parameter.

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem, and your solution solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
proxy_pass http://tomcat;
```

The protocol scheme used to connect to Tomcat on port 8080 is fixed and should be `http` or `https`. The `$scheme` of this `server` block happens to be `http`, but there is no good reason to use that variable for the proxied connection.

By default, `nginx` will pass the requested URI to the proxied connection transparently, so there is no need to provide a URI on the `proxy_pass` statement, unless something has to be changed.

Using `$request_uri` is problematic when there are URL encoded characters (such as during a login sequence where a landing page is passed as a parameter) as it is the raw request and the characters have not been decoded. The `proxy_pass` directive is likely to encoded the encoded characters, turning the request into garbage.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.